# Opening PDFs in browser instead of Word Online SharePoint 19 on Prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm having issues where pdf files added to a document library are opening up in Word Online instead of just the browser. Is there a way to set it up where .pdf files open in the browser and word documents to open in Word Online?

I am using SharePoint 2019 on-premise

I've added the pdf to the Mime Types using the PowerShell script below but the .pdf documents are still opening in word online.

```
$webApplication = Get-SPWebApplication("webapp URL")
$webApplication.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("application/pdf")
$webApplication.Update()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress the WOPI binding using [New-SPWopiSuppressionSetting](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spwopisuppressionsetting?view=sharepoint-ps).

This will open the PDF in the method the browser is able to handle it, i.e. with non-IE browsers it will open with the browsers PDF handler. For IE when Acrobat is installed with it's ActiveX control, it should open in Acrobat.